# Speed up fast poisson disk sampling generator in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, random, iterator

I wrote a generator class which implements Fast Poisson Disk Sampling algorithm in Python. I did some optimizations like, `x ** 2 -> x * x`, using unpacking instead of indexing, move unpacking outside of loops and precalculating of constants (like `2 * pi`), but still not very pleased with results. Is it possible to speed up it even more?

```
import math
import random

class PoissonDiskGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, field, r, k=30):
        self.field_x, self.field_y = field
        self.cell_size = math.ceil(r / math.sqrt(2))
        self.grid_size_x, self.grid_size_y = math.ceil(field[0] / self.cell_size), math.ceil(field[1] / self.cell_size)
        self.samples_grid = [
            [None for y in range(math.ceil(self.field_x / self.cell_size))]
            for x in range(math.ceil(self.field_y / self.cell_size))
        ]
        x = random.uniform(0, field[0]), random.uniform(0, field[1])
        self.points = [x]
        self.active_indices = [0]
        self.active_iter = 1
        self.tries = k
        self.radius = r
        self.radius2 = 2 * r
        self.pi2 = 2 * math.pi

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.active_indices:
            point = self.try_place_new_point()
            while not point and self.active_indices:
                point = self.try_place_new_point()
            if not point:
                raise StopIteration
            return point
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def try_place_new_point(self):
        ref_ind = random.choice(self.active_indices)
        for i in range(self.tries):
            point_x, point_y = self.pick_point(self.points[ref_ind])
            grid_x, grid_y = math.floor(point_x / self.cell_size), math.floor(point_y / self.cell_size)
            neighbor_list = self.neighbors(grid_x, grid_y)
            point_ok = True
            if neighbor_list:
                for neighbor in neighbor_list:
                    nb_x, nb_y = neighbor
                    if (point_x - nb_x) * (point_x - nb_x) + (point_y - nb_y) * (point_y - nb_y) < self.radius * self.radius:
                        point_ok = False
            if point_ok:
                self.points.append((point_x, point_y))
                self.active_indices.append(self.active_iter)
                self.samples_grid[grid_x][grid_y] = self.active_iter
                self.active_iter += 1
                return point_x, point_y
        self.active_indices.remove(ref_ind)
        return None

    def pick_point(self, ref_point):
        ref_x, ref_y = ref_point
        while True:
            rho, theta = random.uniform(self.radius, self.radius2), random.uniform(0, self.pi2)
            pick_x, pick_y = ref_x + rho * math.cos(theta), ref_y + rho * math.sin(theta)
            if 0 < pick_x < self.field_x and 0 < pick_y < self.field_y:
                return pick_x, pick_y

    def grid_to_point(self, grid_x, grid_y):
        try:
            return self.samples_grid[grid_x][grid_y]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def neighbors(self, grid_x, grid_y):
        neighbors_list = (
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x, grid_y),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x, grid_y - 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x, grid_y + 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 1, grid_y),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 1, grid_y - 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 1, grid_y + 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 1, grid_y),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 1, grid_y - 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 1, grid_y + 1),

            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 2, grid_y + 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 2, grid_y),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 2, grid_y - 1),

            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 1, grid_y + 2),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x, grid_y + 2),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 1, grid_y + 2),

            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 2, grid_y + 1),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 2, grid_y),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 2, grid_y - 1),

            self.grid_to_point(grid_x + 1, grid_y - 2),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x, grid_y - 2),
            self.grid_to_point(grid_x - 1, grid_y - 2)
        )
        return (self.points[ngb] for ngb in neighbors_list if ngb is not None)
```

Profiling code:

```
import cProfile
import pstats

def full_gen_run():
    size = (15000, 15000)
    point_gen = PoissonDiskGenerator(size, 100)
    while True:
        try:
            next(point_gen)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    print(len(point_gen.points))

cProfile.run('full_gen_run()', 'profile_stats')
stats = pstats.Stats('profile_stats')
stats.strip_dirs()
stats.sort_stats('tottime')
stats.print_stats('poissondisk.py:')
```

Visualisation code:

```
import pyglet
import time
from pyglet.window import key
from pyge.poissondisk import PoissonDiskGenerator

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    SPEED = 10

    def __init__(self):
        super(Game, self).__init__(1280, 720)
        self.size_x = 20000
        self.size_y = 20000

        self.set_caption(pyglet.version)
        self.fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(self)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60)
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.viewpos = (self.size_x / 2, self.size_y / 2)
        self.zoom = self.size_x / self.height

        self.key_state_handler = key.KeyStateHandler()
        self.push_handlers(self.key_state_handler)

        self.point_gen = PoissonDiskGenerator((self.size_x, self.size_y), 100)
        self.start_time = None
        self.generation_done = False

    def update(self, _):
        if not self.generation_done:
            if self.start_time is None:
                self.start_time = time.perf_counter()
                print('Points...')
            time_good = True
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            while time_good:
                time_good = time.perf_counter() - start_time < 0.01
                try:
                    point = next(self.point_gen)
                except StopIteration:
                    self.generation_done = True
                    end_time = time.perf_counter()
                    print('OK ({:.2f} ms)'.format((end_time - self.start_time) * 1000))
                    break
                self.batch.add(1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS, None, ('v2f', point))

        if self.key_state_handler[key.W]:
            self.viewpos = (self.viewpos[0], self.viewpos[1] + 10 * self.SPEED)
        if self.key_state_handler[key.S]:
            self.viewpos = (self.viewpos[0], self.viewpos[1] - 10 * self.SPEED)
        if self.key_state_handler[key.A]:
            self.viewpos = (self.viewpos[0] - 10 * self.SPEED, self.viewpos[1])
        if self.key_state_handler[key.D]:
            self.viewpos = (self.viewpos[0] + 10 * self.SPEED, self.viewpos[1])
        if self.key_state_handler[key.E]:
            self.zoom -= 0.01 * self.SPEED
            if self.zoom < 1.0:
                self.zoom = 1.0
        if self.key_state_handler[key.Q]:
            self.zoom += 0.01 * self.SPEED

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        pyglet.gl.glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        pyglet.gl.glMatrixMode(pyglet.gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        pyglet.gl.glLoadIdentity()
        pyglet.gl.glOrtho(self.viewpos[0] - self.width / 2 * self.zoom, self.viewpos[0] + self.width / 2 * self.zoom,
                          self.viewpos[1] - self.height / 2 * self.zoom, self.viewpos[1] + self.height / 2 * self.zoom,
                          -1, 1)
        pyglet.gl.glMatrixMode(pyglet.gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        self.batch.draw()
        self.fps_display.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

[image: screenshot of visualisation]

Comment: What is a typical `r` for testing? Can you post some test code that will exercise this thing?

Comment: @Reinderien I test it by calling next() until StopIteration raises, and gather profiling stats using cProfile. This code generate ~14179 points with r=100 and field=(15000, 15000) in about 7 sec. UPD: added code to question

Comment: OK; but that's profiling, not testing. What kind of tests can you run against the output to ensure that it's correct?

Comment: @Reinderien sorry, I didn't write any tests. I just visualize an output using pyglet.

Comment: Please edit your question to show that code, as well as a screenshot.

Comment: @Reinderien added code and screenshot you requested

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to speed up it even more?

Yes. Use Numpy. It's not really worth thinking about any other micro-optimizations until you've attempted to vectorize this thing with a proper numerical library.

Here's a tutorial on how to start out vectorizing with Numpy:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html

There are many others.

Comment: Any tips on what I can vectorize in this algorithm?

Comment: Yes; I'm writing up an example

Comment: As I see after some searching, Fast Poisson Disk algorithm can't be vectorized, because samples cannot be generated independently; each sample depends on the positions of the other samples. I can use sample elimination algorithm, but it's a different problem, that requires research to understand will it be faster or not. Question remains opened.

Comment: @Hadwig: Maybe have a look at [this implementation](https://scipython.com/blog/poisson-disc-sampling-in-python/), it uses at least some `numpy`. Would be interesting to see if it is faster/slower than yours.

Comment: @Graipher This code spend 14.464 sec, while mine 8.158 sec, with same generation parametrs. Problem here - `numpy` `ndarray` work slower than python lists when you simply need to get/set one value many times. They very fast in vector calculations, but here it does not help at all.